# web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, m2eclipse

Consider:

[image]

When I create a simple [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) project in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) I am getting this error:

> web.xml is missing and `<failOnMissingWebXml>` is set to
>   true

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to add the `maven-war-plugin`. This is an implicit plugin where the default value for that configuration property is true. You need to explicitly declare it and set the configuration property to false. See more [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). Or you can add an empty web.xml

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can do it also like this:

1. Right click on **Deployment Descriptor**   in   **Project Explorer**.
2. Select **Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub**.

It will generate **WEB-INF** folder in **src/main/webapp** and an **web.xml** in it.

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend adding boilerplate to the code, just because your build tool gives an error.

Comment: @MartijnBurger Can you enlighten us about the possible repercussions of the above hack and if possible also add some other alternatives? - would help novice programmers like me. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer below for an alternative. The solution above is not wrong, it is just that you should always strive to make your final product as clean as possible. With the solution above, your final product will end up with an unnecessary `web.xml`  file. You should fix this problem in you build tool (i.e. maven) instead.

Comment: You may also refer : http://eggsylife.co.uk/2009/12/20/eclipse-galileo-cannot-nest-src-folder/

Comment: this will add unnecessary file in your project and other thing is that web.xml approcah is old . if you want to remove this error then just force update the maven error will be gone

Answer (score 414):

This is a maven error. It says that it is expecting a web.xml file in your project because it is a web application, as indicated by `<packaging>war</packaging>`. However, for recent web applications a web.xml file is totally optional. Maven needs to catch up to this convention. 
Add this to your maven `pom.xml` to let maven catch up and you don't need to add a useless `web.xml` to your project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is a better solution than adding an empty `web.xml` because this way your final product stays clean, your are just changing your build parameters.

For more current versions of maven you can also use the shorter version:

```
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

Comment: This answer is more logical than others.

Comment: Add a missing step: you need to right click on `project -> Maven -> Update Project` to make this configuration come into effect.

Comment: If you are using a  in Servlet 3.0+ environment and have any implementation of a ``Interface WebApplicationInitializer`` this answer is the correct approach. It's the sensible way to solve this problem - no point adding the ``web.xml`` after taking steps to live without it!

Comment: This answer is more logical than others

Comment: This is a better answer than creating an empty web.xml

Comment: Works even without Maven > Update Project. So it isn't needed.

Comment: Please consider updating your answer for a shorter configuration, as suggested [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35519476/859604). Including `<properties><failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml></properties>` suffices instead of the more verbose plugin configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer, however this only works for more recent versions of maven. The first solution will always work.

Comment: @MartijnBurger I found that maven doc says default value of failOnMissingWebXml of maven-war-plugin is false, so why we need to set it false explicitly? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

Comment: @frank According to the docs that default is: `Starting with 3.1.0, this property defaults to false if the project depends on the Servlet 3.0 API or newer.` So for versions before 3.1.0 you need to set it explicitly.

Comment: <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> HELPED ME

Comment: Starting with v3.1.0 of the plugin, this property defaults to false if the project depends on the Servlet 3.0 API or newer (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml).

Answer (score 34):

If you already have web.xml under /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF but you still get error "web.xml is missing and  is set to true", you could check if you have included **/src/main/webapp** in your project source.

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. You can check this by right clicking your project, and open its Properties dialogue, and then "Deployment Assembly", where you can add Folder /src/main/webapp. Save the setting, and then,
2. Go to Eclipse menu Project -> Clean... and clean the project, and the error should go away.

(I verified this with Eclipse Mars)

Comment: Eperienced the same issue under "Eclipse Mars" and Your described solution works perfect! Thanks

Comment: did not work for me... I am already having those folders and I even tried setting web.xml missing false. It is not working....

Answer (score 20):

You can also do this which is less verbose

```
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

Comment: The most elegant solution IMHO. See [doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#failOnMissingWebXml) (and an old eclipse [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471622) which prevented this solution to work, now solved).

Answer (score 20):

If you use Spring Tool Suite, option for Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub is moved under Java EE Tools, so you:

1. **Right click** on your **project**
2. Select **Java EE Tools**
3. Select **Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub option**

This will create web.xml file inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ folder, and of course remove error from Maven's pom.xml file.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

I have the same problem. After studying and googling, I have resolved my problem:

Right click on the project folder, go to `Java EE Tools`, select `Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub`. This will create `web.xml` in the folder `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`.

Comment: I would not recommend adding boilerplate to the code, just because your build tool gives an error.

Answer (score 11):

Eclipse recognizes incorrect default `webapp` directory.
Therefore we should set clearly it by `maven-war-plugin`.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Once saving this setting, the error will never occour if removed it.
(I cannot explain why.)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, even though I had `'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/'` folder with correct `web.xml`.

The problem disappeared after I recreated (maven->eclipse) configuration with
`Maven build..` I executed `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`

And then I used `Maven -> Update Project` to add (eclipse->maven) plugin specific options.

Comment: The same here, although I used git reset --hard HEAD

Comment: Thank you, this helped me too. Right click -> Maven -> Update Project

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue in eclipse only, everything worked fine in Maven command line, and my web.xml file existed. It was a mature project (already deployed out in production) that was impacted. My problem was tied to the eclipse metadata.  There was an issue with one of the files in my .settings/ folder, specifically org.eclipse.wst.common.component had been changed.  I was able to restore this file to its prior version, which resolved the issue in my case.

Note that Yuci's answer did not work for me, when I tried to click on Deployment Assembly in the eclipse properties, I got an error that said "the currently displayed page contains invalid values."

Comment: I had the same situation and had to restore the org.eclipse.wst.common.component file from my .settings/ folder and my project works now, apparently the component's content was deleted, so it hasn't the path to my web.xml file. Also when I tried to open Deployment Assembly in the eclipse properties got the same error: "the currently displayed page contains invalid values."
I found this answer a bit late but this's how I solve it.
Great answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

*For Project with web.xml present*
Project-->Properties-->Deployment Assembly,where you can add Folder src/main/webapp.
Save change.
Clean the project to get going.

*For Project with web.xml not present*
Set failOnMissingWebXml to false in pom.xml under properties tag.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

Go and right click on Deployment Descriptor and click Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this tags to your pom.xml

```
 <properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following XML Code before the closing tag ***</ project >*** in POM.XML

```
<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
```

This should solve your error for the missing *WEB.XML* file.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to create a web.xml just elcipse wants it, even there is no need. This is the case if you have servlet conatiner embedded or living without xml cfg like spring-boot does.
The you just diable JavaEE (useless stuff) in eclipse on project level or global

```
Eclipse/STS>Windows>Preferences>JavaEE>Doclet>Webdoclet> "uncheck" DeploymentDescriptor > OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove files from **-web/.setting&**-admin/.setting

[image: 1]

Comment: this option worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Select your project
and select the "Deployment Descriptor" option
and then choose "Generate Deployment Descriptor stub"

Answer (score 0):

The step of : Select your project and select the "Deployment Descriptor" option and then choose "Generate Deployment Descriptor stub" works fine. The issue is that it is not always the case that we need web.xml, so it is best to append    false to pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the `project --> New --> Other --> Standard Deployment Descriptor(web.xml)`

[image: 1]

then press **Next** it will create `WEB-INF` folder with a `web.xml` file inside.

[image: 2]

That's it done.

Answer (score 0):

My project had nothing to do with war, but the same error. I had to remove project from eclipse, delete all eclipse files from the project folder and reimport maven project.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Eclipse, you can do this graphically as follows:

1. Find "Overview" tab at the bottom of editor pane
2. Open "Properties" line button
3. Click Create... button on the right
4. Input <Name, Value> pair
5. Press OK
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

Create WEB-INF folder in src/webapp, and include web.xml page inside the WEB-INF folder then

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the project, go to *Maven -> Update Project...* , then check the *Force Update of Snapshots/Releases* , then click *Ok*. It's done!