# web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true - web.xml is there and can't edit deployment assembly

Tags: eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse and I am getting the error "web.xml is missing and  is set to true" in my pom.xml even though the web.xml isn't missing.

[web.xml missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5kWH.png)

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835033/web-xml-is-missing-and-failonmissingwebxml-is-set-to-true) it's suggested that we update Deployment Assembly in properties, but I can't do that because I get the following error:

[deployment assembly error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAHIK.png)

I've also attempted to update the Maven build but I get an error when I try that.

What can I do to fix these issues?

Comment: I suppose you are creating a WAR (Web application ARchive) project, right?

Comment: Where do you place your `web.xml`? Is your POM packaging as WAR?

Comment: I am creating a WAR project.  My web.xml is located in my WEB-INF folder, and my server has a web.xml as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error from maven, it is saying that is expecting a `web.xml` file because the project is defined as a web project on `pom.xml` through `<packaging>war</packaging>`. As in some web application `web.xml` is optional, instead creating an empty `web.xml` you can overwrite the default value from the property `failOnMissingWebXml` on `maven-war-plugin` adding the following values on your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you need a `web.xml` file on your project, you can create it like this:

[image: Maven WAR project default structure]

`web.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>stackoverflow</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

To avoid some problems with IDE, try to run `mvn clean install` from prompt. If it works, you should check IDE files on the project (e.g. Eclipse has .project .setting and .classpath files who has some information that can be generating the error).

Comment: A side note: since Maven WAR plugin 3.0.0, the default value for `failOnMissingWebXml` has been changed from true to false. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/

Comment: The thing is I already have a web.xml in that location.  So the issue is it's not seeing it, but I can't point it correctly because of the error I'm getting from the Deployment Assembly preference box.

Comment: When you run 'mvn clean install' on a prompt, you get the same error?

Comment: I haven't tried it from the command line but when I try to update the project in Maven in Eclipse I get "Updating Maven Project has encountered a problem" which is a null pointer exception but it doesn't tell me where

Comment: Try to run 'mvn clean install' on a prompt.

Comment: OK, so your problem is with your IDE, you are using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, using Eclipse Neon 4.6.3.  I believe my main problem here is the error I get when trying to access Deployment Assembly.

Comment: try to delete (create a backup) all configuration files and folders (.project and .settings) on the root of the project. Also .classpath (sometimes Eclipse can create it).

Comment: Close the project on Eclipse, through System Explorer try to delete (create a backup) all configuration files and folders (.project and .settings) on the root of the project. Also .classpath (sometimes Eclipse can create it). And then open it on Eclipse and see if the errors persist...