# Why I am getting error "web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true" even when web.xml is present under WEB-INF?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web.xml

Why I am getting error `"web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true"` even when web.xml is present under WEB-INF?

This is not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835033/web-xml-is-missing-and-failonmissingwebxml-is-set-to-true?noredirect=1&lq=1). **My issue is different as I already have `web.xml` file in my `WEB-INF` folder, but still getting the error.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835033/web-xml-is-missing-and-failonmissingwebxml-is-set-to-true)

Comment: totally different question, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a corrupted Eclipse-specific settings file.

Check out the answer to [Spring cannot find file in classpath, but it's right there at the root of the war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52049748/spring-cannot-find-file-in-classpath-but-its-right-there-at-the-root-of-the-wa).

For me, both problems had the same root cause.