# Spring cannot find file in classpath, but it's right there at the root of the war file

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, classloader

I have a project using the standard Maven web app layout, deployed within Tomcat 8.5 in Eclipse Photon (with latest updates).

Inside of `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\applicationContext.xml`, there is an `<import resource="classpath:/other-spring-stuff.xml" />`

I verified the `other-spring-stuff.xml` which is normally sitting in `src/main/resources`, appears in the root of the `WAR` generated by `mvn install`.

But when trying to run the app in Tomcat within Eclipse, I get:

```
20:37:17 SEVERE: Servlet [servletSpringDispatcher] in web application [/myapp] threw load() exception - 2018-08-27 @{org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup} 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:227)
```

I don't really know whether this is a problem with Maven, Eclipse, or Spring.

What can cause this? This is actually in a project that was working fine until yesterday, and nothing changed on the project configuration.

Comment: any reason why is it looking for spring.xml instead of other-spring-stuff.xml? is it just an example or did u rename the file?

Comment: I was just trying to make it more self-explanatory for the question. The actual file is spring.xml

Comment: your other-spring-stuff.xml is still under src/main/resources? can you try the `classpath*:other-spring-stuff.xml` without the `/`

Comment: I decided to delete the project and re-checkout from the master branch. Now my error changed to `web.xml is missing and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to true`, as in this unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385888/why-i-am-getting-error-web-xml-is-missing-and-failonmissingwebxml-is-set-to-t

Comment: answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835033/web-xml-is-missing-and-failonmissingwebxml-is-set-to-true

Comment: NOT answered there. That question (31835033) deals with an actual missing web.xml. More like the other question I linked (51385888), mine is not actually missing.

Comment: Attach the web.xml.Also check your eclipse deployment assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem (*spring.xml not found*) and secondary problem (*false report of missing web.xml*) were both resolved by taking the following steps:

1. Delete the project from the workspace, but keep it on the file system
2. Go to the project's filesystem location and delete `.project`, `.classpath`, and `.settings/`
3. Re-Import the project into Eclipse, select *Existing Maven Project* as project type
4. To prevent reocurrence: remove `.project`, `.classpath`, and `.settings/*` from git and then add them to `.gitignore`

I believe the root cause is that one of these Eclipse-specific config files that was checked into the repo had become corrupted and/or incompatible with my version of Eclipse. Also: **these files seem to contain absolute-path references to things in the workspace, so they break when the project is checked out unmodified to a different location**.