# Maven Package still fails without web.xml even with <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have been working on removing the web.xml file from my Java web project and switching to Java-based configuration. The application runs fine without the web.xml on Eclipse, but when I try to Maven Package it, I get the error shown below.

First, I just tried setting the version of maven-war-plugin to be >3. This did not fix the problem. I also have tried editing the project pom to include the following tag:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, I have continued to get the same error I was getting before:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) on project myproject-web: The specified web.xml file 'I:\myproject\web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml' does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

Full Trace:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) on project myproject-web: The specified web.xml file 'I:\myproject\web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml' does not exist -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) on project myproject-web: The specified web.xml file 'I:\myproject\web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml' does not exist
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: The specified web.xml file 'I:\myproject\web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml' does not exist
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.handleDeploymentDescriptors (WarProjectPackagingTask.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.packaging.WarProjectPackagingTask.performPackaging (WarProjectPackagingTask.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildWebapp (AbstractWarMojo.java:489)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.AbstractWarMojo.buildExplodedWebapp (AbstractWarMojo.java:406)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.WarMojo.performPackaging (WarMojo.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.WarMojo.execute (WarMojo.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Is there any other way I can fix this error besides setting the failOnMissingWebXml tag to false?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658748/214525) mentions the same syntax but uses version 2.6 of the plugin while you use 2.1.1. Can you update the plugin's version?

Comment: @f1sh thanks for replying! I have tried updating my version explicitly to 3.0.0. I have also tried 2.6. I updated my post above to show the new version still failing

Comment: First I would suggest to use the most recent version of the plugin which is 3.2.3 and also check https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/